# Como selecionar uma tag especifica HTML quando não se tem id ou name e (raramente tem uma class) usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte codigo HTML:

```
<div class="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>TITULO DO BOX</tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="classeTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Esporte:</td>
                <td>Futebol</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Esporte:</td>
                <td>Volei</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Esporte:</td>
                <td>Basquete</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div>
```

No momento, eu tenho varias `div` sem identificação nenhuma e dentro dessas `div` eu tenho 2 `table`, a primeira `table` tem o **TITULO DO BOX** e apenas isso, já a segunda `table` tem o conteúdo do box porém tem uma `class` que pode ajudar, porém essa mesma `class` é usada em varios outros lugares, então não daria pra ser usada como um identificador, o que poderia ser usado, seria o (**TITULO DO BOX** + `class="classeTable"`), como eu poderia juntar essas 2 informações pra identificar exatamente que eu gostaria de pegar os valores *Futebol/Volei/Basquete*?

Uma solução seria:

```
$(".classeTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)").text();
$(".classeTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)").text();
$(".classeTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)").text();
```

Mas como eu mencionei anteriormente, essa `class="classeTable"` está sendo usada em diversos lugares, então o jQuery não saberia ao certo qual `class="classeTable"` escolher.

Algo assim seria o ideal:

```
$("TITULO DO BOX .classeTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)").text();
$("TITULO DO BOX .classeTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)").text();
$("TITULO DO BOX .classeTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)").text();
```

Porém não sei ao certo como fazer isso e se tem como fazer isso. Talvez tenha algum jeito diferente que eu não tenho conhecimento.

Comment: Não tem muito sentido a pergunta. Tudo bem, você quer pegar os textos citados dentro de uma determinada tabela que não tem um identificador único e próprio, blz. A pergunta que eu faço é: por que você quer pegar o texto, por exemplo, "futebol" dessa tabela? O que faz dessa tabela especial? Aí você poderia responder: "porque tem o texto 'futebol' que eu quero pegar"... Sim, mas só essa tabela tem esse texto? Se for só ela, basta fazer um loop nas tabelas e ver qual que tem o texto "futebol". Simples assim.

Comment: Só complementando, para selecionar um elemento, alguma coisa de diferente dos outros ele deve ter, seja uma letra que os outros não tem, uma vírgula, uma string.. enfim, qualquer coisa que possa diferenciá-lo dos outros irmãos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível  sim, porém da forma que está, é *terrivelmente complicado*. Isso porque `<tr>TITULO DO BOX</tr>` é inválido. O navegador irá remover esse texto e irá adiciona-lo antes da tabela.

Antes, é necessário corrigir sua primeira tabela. O correto é `<tr><td>TITULO DO BOX</td></tr>`.

**Feito isso, vamos ao código (já comentado):**

```js
/* Captura o elemento "tr" que contém o texto "TITULO DO BOX" */
let trs = $('table tbody tr:contains("TITULO DO BOX")')

          /* Retorna para o elemento pai, o table */
          .parents('table')
          
          /* Captura o próximo elemento da hierarquia */
          .next()
          
          /* Captura todos os elementos "td" que estão na segunda posição */
          .find('tr td:eq(1)');

/* Percorre todos os elementos e exibe o valor na tela. */
$.map( trs, el => {
  console.log( el.innerText )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>TITULO DO BOX</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="classeTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Esporte:</td>
                <td>Futebol</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Esporte:</td>
                <td>Volei</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Esporte:</td>
                <td>Basquete</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div>
```

Caso você possa refatorar, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
/* Captura o elemento "tr" que contém o texto "TITULO DO BOX" */
let trs = $('table thead th:contains("TITULO DO BOX")')

          /* Retorna para o elemento pai, o table */
          .parents('table')
          
          /* Captura todos os elementos "td" que estão na segunda posição */
          .find('tr td:eq(1)');

/* Percorre todos os elementos e exibe o valor na tela. */
$.map( trs, el => {
  console.log( el.innerText )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
    <table class="classeTable">
        <thead>
          <tr colspan="2">
            <th>TITULO DO BOX</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Esporte:</td>
                <td>Futebol</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Esporte:</td>
                <td>Volei</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Esporte:</td>
                <td>Basquete</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div>
```